How to drive P-Channel MOSFET For Highvolatge Precharge Ciruit in BMS Application
I am designing a BMS for 24S NMC (100.8 V) and looking for perfect solution for precharge on high side. I designed this circuit. It would be awesome if you folks comment on this and please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. It’s my first time using P-channel MOSFET so thats what I came up with.
Edit: the MOSFET is used as switch in this schematic.


Is it linear control of a charging current or, operated as a switch? Please amend your answer rather than only leaving a comment. You should also state the range of supply voltages that are valid.

@Ajay can you ask a specific question of where you are stuck?

The gate drive of 17 V is a bit close to Q43 Vgs abs max, 10 V would be plenty.
Do you really want over 300 mW dissipation in R136? How fast does Q43 need to be switched?

17v is choosen so that the bms can operate even with 8s battery pack which with give around 5v at vgs, enough to do a precharge sequence. it is not switched constantly just switched on for a few seconds for precharge and then turned off after main contactor closes. so no super fast speed needed. so i should increase the resistance of r136.

i settled for r135 = 20k, r136 = 100k

There are photovoltaic isolators that can generate a turning on voltage for high-side switch:
Note: You can connect more of them outputs in series (inputs in parallel) if higher gate-source voltage is needed.

